# C# Automapper Ignore Property When Null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am creating an Automapper mapping between my `AccountEditViewModel` (View Model used for editing a user) and my `User` (Data Model representing a User in the database). If the password field is filled in, I want to encrypt that password and store it however if it is null in the I want to keep the old password. I have tried the code below however it is wrong, model.Ignore() doesn't return a string value. What is the best way of going about this. Can I accomplish this using the `ForMember()` method or do I need a custom resolver?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountEditViewModel, User>()
                .ForMember(model => model.Password, model => model.MapFrom(user => user.Password != null ? EncryptPassword(user.Password) : model.Ignore()));
```

Comment: Similar questions [How to ignore null values for all source members during mapping in Automapper 6?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43947475) and [AutoMapper.Map ignore all Null value properties from source object](//stackoverflow.com/q/12514084)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountEditViewModel, User>()
.ForMember(model => model.Password, model => model.Ignore()) 
.AfterMap((src, dst) =>
                    {
                        if (src.Password != null)
                            dst.Password= EncryptPassword(src.Password);

                    });
```

Comment: You need to add a ForMember(model => model.Password, model => model.Ignore()) before the AfterMap() call the mapper is no longer handling the mapping

Comment: This does not work when you use LinQ expressions of the automapper.